# Choose multiple class name and get childnode inside that class with PHP DOMXpath

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

```
<div id="conti">
  <div class="no_matter"></div>
  <div class="row-0">
    <b></b>
    <span>
      <i>"child node that i want to get"</i>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="row-1">
    <b></b>
    <span>
      <i>"child node that i want to get"</i>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="row-0">
    <b></b>
    <span>
      <i>"child node that i want to get"</i>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="row-1">
    <b></b>
    <span>
      <i>"child node that i want to get"</i>
    </span>
  </div>

  ...
  ...
  class row-0 and row-1 repeats itself
  ...
  ...

</div>
```

This is the HTML that i want to parse and get contents. I want `text node inside <i> tag`. I am using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXpath`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.meal.org/anter.php');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$row = $xpath->query('//*[@class="row-0" ]');  //my problem begins there. I want both 'row-0' and 'row-1'. How i am gonna choose multiple class?

//and than how i am gonna get `<i>` tag inside every `row-0` and `row-1` class and get the text node?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all that with the following XPath query:

```xml
//*[starts-with(@class,"row-")]/span/i/text()
```

[MDN on starts-with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with):

> The `starts-with` checks whether the first string starts with the second string and returns true or false.

If you are interested in all text nodes in these rows, so also the ones in the `b` tags, and any other tags that might be in those rows, then use the double slash:

```xml
//*[starts-with(@class,"row-")]//text()
```

Comment: better, more clear answer. Is there a good documentation to learn `DOMxpath::query`

Comment: There are several resources, like [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp).

Answer (score 3):

```
$iTags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="row-0" or @class="row-1"]/span/i');

foreach ($iTags as $iTag) {
    var_dump(trim($iTag->nodeValue));
}
```

Comment: wow. didn't know `/span/i` thing at the end. One mre question: How can i choose both `/span/i` and `/b`? lets assume `<b>` has a text node too

Comment: One way would be to combine queries using the `|` like so: `$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="row-0" or @class="row-1"]/span/i | //div[@class="row-0" or @class="row-1"]/b');`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fammiliar with XPath, so I'm looping trough each `<div>` element using `DOMDocument()`. Check wheter it has a attribute class with value row-0 or row-1. If so then get each element `<i>` and dump the nodeValue.

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div){
    if($div->getAttribute('class') == 'row-0' OR $div->getAttribute('class') == 'row-1'){
        foreach($div->getElementsByTagName('i') as $i){
            var_dump($i->nodeValue);
        }
    }
}
```